# IIS is Redirecting to a 404 Error Page When There is a Hash Value (#) in the URL That Includes a Period

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7.5, url-routing

I've come across some behavior that I can't seem to figure out. Some users notified me that tumblr urls were not working for my site.

Tumblr is adding a hash (#) plus some random characters of which include a period.

An example Tumblr generated URL for my site looks like the following:
http://www.killsometime.com/videos/10747/First-Time-News-Anchor-Fail#i0OJ0Uc752hQkZHO.18

The actual URL on the site is:
http://www.killsometime.com/videos/10747/First-Time-News-Anchor-Fail

You can see that tumblr is adding a hash value with a period mixed in. You can use that url to test the behavior im speaking of.

IIS is choking on these values. It loads the page correctly, then immediately does a redirect to a 404 error.

In my web.config I have the following setting to allow periods:

`<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />`

Heres my route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Video",
            url: "videos/{MediaID}/{MediaTitle}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Videos", action = "Video", MediaID = "", MediaTitle = "" },
            constraints: new { MediaID = @"\d+" }
        );
```

I'm racking my brain with this one. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: It has something to do with that period. Still not sure what's happening though.

Comment: Could it have to do with my route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. It didnt have to do with IIS. I was running a very old version of jquery.history which is no longer supported.